# VSTS Git-credentials not longer working for external tools?

Tags: git, azure-devops, credentials

Since the last 3 days I experience problems when connecting with externals tools to Git repos on VSTS. I use GitKraken and I always had to generate Git-credentials in VSTS and the use them. Everything worked fine.

In the last days now GitKraken started to prompt for login data again. Using the Git shell directly works without any problems. After trying several things (re-install GitKraken, reset Git-credentials in VSTS) I recognized that generating a personal access token (PAT) in VSTS solves this problem.

I inspected the HTTPS traffic between GitKraken and VSTS and found responses with code `401` and the message `TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.` when using my Git-credentials.

Does anyone know if Git credentials are outdated or am I missing something here?

**Edit**

GitKraken will just show the login prompt again and again without giving me any error message.

Comment: Does the problem happen when you start to use GitKraken or just happen in last few days? What's GitKraken GUI show when you fail to connect with VSTS git repo and can you add related screen shots? And what if you use  Alternate credentials or SSH key (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/auth-overview) for authentication in GitKraken?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I edited the question a bit. There is no screenshot I could share. This is why I used Fiddler to inspect the traffic behind the scenes. No I didn't try SSH so far because PAT worked out in the end.

Comment: Can you still reproduce the issue with PAT now? And I use the same PAT for GitKraken authentication,  and it works fine.

Comment: No I can't reproduce it with PAT. The point is that it works with PAT and does not work with credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue by inputting VSTS login email address and password in GitKarken.

But for other authentication Types, such as PAT, SSH key and Alternate credentials, they can work as expected.

It’s not the issue for VSTS itself, but the authentication issue for GitKraken. And I have already feedback the issue to GitKarken.

Answer (score 1):

Were you able to overcome the issue? GitKraken now integrates with VSTS, so definitely check out the latest update! https://blog.axosoft.com/gitkraken-integration-vsts/